# Fresh Yii Boilerplate Project Reports An Error

Tags: php, yii, haml, yii-extensions

I've generated a new project using the Yii-​​boilerplate(Haml branch), but there is an error:

```
Use of undefined constant HAMLPHP_ROOT - assumed 'HAMLPHP_ROOT' in \yii-boilerplate\protected\extensions\yiihppie\vendors\HamlPHP\src\HamlPHP\Lang\Nodes\DoctypeNode.php.
```

Any advices on how to solve it?

**Update:** `HAMLPHP_ROOT` is already defined in `\yii-boilerplate\protected\extensions\yiihppie\vendors\HamlPHP\src\HamlPHP\Config.php` as

```
define('HAMLPHP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've managed to resolve the issue. The problem was that `\yii-boilerplate\protected\extensions\yiihppie\vendors\HamlPHP\src\HamlPHP\HamlPHP.php` includes wrong `Config.php`

```
require_once 'Config.php';
```

It actually includes `Config.php` from the Pear directory, not from the current one. So I've specified it unambigiously as

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

define of the constant  HAMLPHP_ROOT in index.php or config.php